# Showing a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $a \in G$, $a$ is a fixed element. Let $H=[b\in G | bab^{-1}\in \langle a\rangle ]$. I need to show that H is a subgroup of G. I know the theorems for subgroup tests. I am new to the abstract algebra so a methodological answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: Ah sorry. My mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: I still suspect that you haven't copied the problem correctly.

Comment: :( I am still new to the matjax. Fixed it. I am sorry

Comment: I have no idea why that would be a subgroup. It looks a lot like something else, which _is_ a subgroup. Look very carefully at every single detail. You're absolutely certain that what you posted is the right problem?

Comment: Yes. I am certain.

Comment: Can you please tell what goes wrong? Probably even if you put up your ideas, that would be helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the word "finite". Yes, the third version is a subgroup of $G$.

Hints: If $b\in H$ that says $bab^{-1} = a^n$ for some integer $n$, right? And that says $ba=a^nb$.

You need to show that if $b,c\in H$ then $bc\in H$. You know that $ba=a^nb$ and $ca=a^mc$ for some integers $n,m$. You need to show that there exists an integer $N$ with $bca=a^Nbc$. An *example* of why this would be so, assuming that $m=3$:
$$bca = ba^3c=(ba)a^2c=a^nba^2c=a^n(ba)a=a^{2n}bac=a^{3n}bc.$$An argument something like that will work in general.

Where the finiteness comes in is in showing that if $b\in H$ then $b^{-1}\in H$. And a hint for that is that since $G$ is finite $b$ must have finite order, which implies that $b^{-1}=\dots$

Comment: $b^{-1}=e$ which means $b^{-1}\in H$?

Comment: No. First, what does it mean to say $b$ has finite order?

Comment: that there exists smallest positive integer n such that $b^{n}=e$?

Comment: Right. That says $b(b^{n-1})=e$, so $b^{-1}=b^{n-1}$. And now you can finish the proof. (Or not, but I'm out of hints for today...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that:

1. $H$ is not empty.
2. $h\in H\implies h^{-1}\in H$
3. $h,k\in H\implies hk\in H$

Answer (score 0):

*A short version:*

As $G$ is a finite group, all inverses of an element  are positive powers of that element. There results that $H$ is but the *normaliser* of the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$. Now the normaliser of any subgroup is known to be a subgroup.